Got a coroutine object but expected a LIST with async playwright
I'm facing a strange behavior of my project trying to get the cookies of a page using async_playwright. In other project, I open a page, use this: cookies = await page.context.cookies() and the cookies object is a list of dict (actual cookies). But with this new project, the cookies() method returns a coroutine that I can't use because I need to store it in a Mongodatabase. The other project resolves fine and saves the cookies with no errors but this one doesn't. What's going on?
This is my code:
main.py
    def run(self):
        asyncio.run(self.main())

    async def main(self):
        if not self.to_run:
            self.to_run = True
            await self.scraper_service.prepare_browser()


ScraperService.py:
class ScraperService:
    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.playwright = None
        self.browser = None
        self.instance = instance
        if "id" in self.instance:
            self.instance["_id"] = self.instance["id"]
        self.cookie = instance["reqCookies"]
        self.logger = Logger()
        self.options = options
        self.log = self.logger.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
        self.page = None

    async def prepare_browser(self):
        try:
            self.playwright = await async_playwright().start()
            self.browser = await self.playwright.chromium.launch(**self.options)
        except Exception:
            try:
                self.playwright = await async_playwright().start()
                self.browser = await self.playwright.chromium.launch(**self.options)
            except Exception as ex1:
                self.log.error(f"Error launching Playwright: {repr(ex1)}. Finishing execution.", traceback.format_exc())
                sys.exit()

    async def init_scraper(self):
        self.log.info("Starting scraper service")
        try:
            if self.browser is None or not self.browser.is_connected():
                self.log.error("Browser is not connected or is None valued.")
                return
            await self.stop_browser()
            await self.prepare_browser()
            self.page = await self.browser.new_page()
            await self.page.context.add_cookies(self.cookie)
            scraper = PlaywrightScraper(self.page)
            await scraper.launch_playwright()
        except Exception as ex:
            self.log.error(f"Error in init_scraper: {repr(ex)}", traceback.format_exc())

PlaywrightScraper.py:
class PlaywrightScraper:
    def __init__(self, page):
        self.page = page
        self.logger = Logger()
        self.cookiesService = CookiesService()
        self.log = self.logger.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)

    async def launch_playwright(self):
        page = self.page
        await page.goto("https://www.facebook.com/groups/feed/", wait_until='load')
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        cookies_object = await page.context.cookies() # Returns a coroutine object
        new_cookie = cookies_object
        self.cookiesService.update("ID", new_cookie) # Pymongo sync API, works fine in other project but here gets a 'coroutine' and throws error.

